# Write this in less CSS code?

Tags: css

I am writing some CSS transitions of 5 different elements (medals/badges). I feel like I have done it the non-opimized way, so I wonder if it is possible to write the same, but with less code?

Here is the code:

```
#nav .badges { float:left; height: 173px; width: 173px; background-color: #fff; /*margin:  0 50px 50px 0;*/ display: block; margin-left: 21px; margin-bottom: 20px; -webkit-border-radius: 100px; -moz-border-radius: 100px; border-radius: 100px; }
   #slidingDoors-bronze-badge { background-image: url('../images/menu-badge-bronse_01.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-bronse_02.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-gull-hover.png') !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-position: 0px 0px, 87px 0px, 0px 180px !important; -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; }
   #slidingDoors-bronze-badge:hover { background-position: -63px 0px, 150px 0px, 0px 0px !important; }
   #slidingDoors-silver-badge { background-image: url('../images/menu-badge-solv_01.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-solv_02.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-gull-hover.png') !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-position: 0px 0px, 87px 0px, 0px 180px !important; -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; }
   #slidingDoors-silver-badge:hover { background-position: -63px 0px, 150px 0px, 0px 0px !important; }
   #slidingDoors-gold-badge { background-image: url('../images/menu-badge-gold_01.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-gold_02.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-gull-hover.png') !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-position: 0px 0px, 87px 0px, 0px 180px !important; -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; }
   #slidingDoors-gold-badge:hover { background-position: -63px 0px, 150px 0px, 0px 0px !important; }
   #slidingDoors-sapphire-badge { background-image: url('../images/menu-badge-safir_01.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-safir_02.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-gull-hover.png') !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-position: 0px 0px, 87px 0px, 0px 180px !important; -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; }
   #slidingDoors-sapphire-badge:hover { background-position: -63px 0px, 150px 0px, 0px 0px !important; }
   #slidingDoors-agat-badge { background-image: url('../images/menu-badge-agat_01.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-agat_02.png'), url('../images/menu-badge-gull-hover.png') !important; background-repeat: no-repeat !important; background-position: 0px 0px, 87px 0px, 0px 180px !important; -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; transition: all 500ms ease-in-out; }
   #slidingDoors-agat-badge:hover { background-position: -63px 0px, 150px 0px, 0px 0px !important; }
```

Comment: when you format your code more readable it is much more inviting for someone to go through it.

Comment: Did you mean less as less OR less as the dynamic stylesheet lang pre-proccesor?

Comment: Use a css sprite if possible.

Comment: @Jrod also sprites have the plus of loading all the "images" at the same time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the only difference is the badge image/color, then why not split it into a couple classes?

```
.coreclass {
   background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
   background-position: 0px 0px, 87px 0px, 0px 180px !important;
   -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
   -moz-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
   -o-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
   -ms-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
   transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.gold { gold stuff here}
.gold:hover { gold hover stuff }
.silver etc...
```

then

```
<div class="coreclass gold">...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

webkit is the last engine that requires a vendor prefix all others support it unprefixed.

http://caniuse.com/#search=transition

```
.coreclass {
    background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
    background-position: 0px 0px, 87px 0px, 0px 180px !important;
   -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
   transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

*(sry to add it as another answer; not enough points for comments yet ...)*